# Send default Select2 option with Post

Tags: php, jquery, html

I spent all day trying to find the answer and I just gave up. Here's my problem, hope you can help me:

I need to pass multiple selections from Select2 through `Post` method. Until here I have no problem if I pick them one by one on the Select2 options, I press submit and everything goes as it should.

The thing is when the page loads: I can see the default value with the last saved options, but if I press submit, without picking anything from the list, I expect that the same value will be passed again through the `Post` method, but no... It goes in blank, erasing the last option saved.

In other words, the only way this thing works is if I pick an option (or multiple options) every time, cause if I don't, the default option is not sent.

Here´s an example of my code so you can check it out and give me a hand:

```
 .....
<title>page1</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myselect").select2();
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$previouschoice="This is one This is two"; //this variable is populated with a mysqli query.
?>
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
            <select id="test" class="myselect" name="mychoices[]" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="<?php echo $previouschoice;?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $previouschoice;?></option>
                <option value="This is one">This is one</option>
                <option value="This is two">This is two</option>
                <option value="This is three">This is three</option>
            </select>
</form>
</body>
```

On page2.php I store the `Post` value into a mysql database for later retrieval, grabbing and concatenating the data in one variable, like this:

```
$mypost =$_POST['mychoices'];
foreach ($mypost as $a) {
    $mychoices=$mychoices.' '.$a;
}
```

So `$mychoices` will eventually be `$previouschoice` back on page1.php

Also tried the initSelection suggested in other posts, with the exact same output. Did this:

```
    $(".myselect").select2().select2("val", null);
    $('#test').val('<?php echo $previouschoice;?>').trigger('change');
```

Please help!

Comment: I dont understand what your problem is can you have another try at explaining

Comment: I would start by changing `name="mychoices[]"` to `name="mychoices"` as I think that will be generating you an array inside an array which might be confusing things

Comment: But if you want to know what youare getting sent in the $_POST Array add a `print_r($_POST);` to your code and it will dump the array in easy to read format

Comment: Also thats a horrible way of saving the $_POST array to the database. Look at `serialize()` or `json_encode()` as that will allow you to dehydrate and then rehydrate the array with a simple command

Comment: Can't change name="mychoices[]" because if I do it won't carry the multiple choices on an array, It will carry only 1 choice.

Comment: And I will do serialize() it later as soon as I figure out this thing....

Comment: What it may be confusing is that Im forcing a new option into the Select2 list. Maybe is not possible?  Even though I can make it appear as a default option, like a chosen option, its really not a option to choose from the pull down list

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your issue completely, but I'll give it a shot.

1. You can pick a few items from the select, submit and retrieve ok.
2. You can read the prior selections when the page reloads
3. Resubmitting "forgets" the selection unless you pick the same choices again.

If this works for you, for ever option, I would add something like

```
<?php if(in_Array("This is one", $previousChoice) echo "selected">
```

Where you would substitute "This is one" where necessary. This assumes $previousChoice is an array, of course.

That way, the options you selected in the first place will automatically be re-selected and should carry over if you submit the form again.

Wayne

Comment: The $previousChoice is not an array, its a string containing the combination of the multiple previous choices, so its like a new option for the Select2 list.